# How to read disabled swing components from Jaws screen reader

Tags: java, swing, jaws-screen-reader

I am using following code :

```
JTextField jtxt = new JTextField("Yahoo");
jtxt.setEnabled(false);
```

When I make component disabled, `JAWS` screen reader skip reading the component. Is there any way we can still read disabled fields?

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to this answer: [Java - setVisible(true) has no effect on GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433809/java-setvisibletrue-has-no-effect-on-gui)

try to set jtxt.setVisible(true) however by right it should still show the text field when it is only disabled.

```
jtxt.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

JAWS will skip disabled fields / component. To make it read, use readonly so it will read the component and tell as readonly also.