# Why doesn't any GUI appear for this code?

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface

Hello everyone and thank you very much for taking your time to help solve me issue.

For some reason, this line of code that is suppose to open a GUI just doesn't run, I slowly copied the exact code from a tutorial on youtube (link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PrPwCKr6WNI)

Here is the code.

```
package game;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    int GWIDTH = 400;
    int GHEIGHT = 300;

    int x, y;

    private Image dbImage;
    private Graphics dbg;

    public Main() {
        setSize(GWIDTH, GHEIGHT);
        setTitle("Game");
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        addMouseListener(new Mouse());

        x = 15;
        y = 15;
    }

    public class Mouse extends MouseAdapter {

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            int xCoord = e.getX();
            int yCoord = e.getY();

            x = xCoord-7;
            y = yCoord-7;
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){

        }
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){

        }
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){

        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        dbImage = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
        dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
        paintComponent(dbg);
        g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, this);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        g.fillOval(x, y, 15, 15);

        repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
    }

}
```

Comment: It's showing for me. Are you sure you're executing the `main` method and not something else? Maybe something (an external running program) is blocking the frame when it's shown?

Comment: Hey good idea, let me check...

Comment: Uhh I actually don't know how... I'm using Netbeans btw can you help me?

Comment: Code works just fine on my PC. As @dabadaba said make sure nothing is blocking the gui.

Comment: The code is working perfectly for me.. As @dabadaba said, check if something else is not allowing it to pop up

Comment: this is my main method though

Comment: that is my only class btw

Comment: @Gamer818 [check this question, it might solve your problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433809/java-setvisibletrue-has-no-effect-on-gui)

Comment: After restarting Netbeans, somehow the problem is fixed! Thanks for everyone that helped anyways.

Comment: It is a pretty poor tutorial that would have you create an image in the paint() method of a JFrame (and also not annotate the method as @Override), and would have you call paintComponent() from paint(), thus making it appear that JFrame has a paintComponent method, and would call repaint() from inside the paintComponent() method, thus creating an infinite loop.